# Deserialize Object JSON Error

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I need to deserialize an object. I have a request class;

```
public class LegacyDataRequest
    {
        public string RowId { get; set; }
        public string SchemaName { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string SelectStatement { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is response class;

```
public class LegacyDataResponse
    {
        public List<KeyData> List { get; set; }
    }
```

I deserialize like that;

```
var res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LegacyDataResponse>>(response.Substring(1, response.Length - 2));
```

And here is the response;

```
[{"Key":"MUSTERI_NO","Data":"26594"},{"Key":"ADRES_KOD","Data":"E"},{"Key":"ADRES","Data":"DENİZ SEMA Site: 3"},{"Key":"SEMT","Data":"DUMLUPINAR"},{"Key":"IL_KOD","Data":"034"},{"Key":"POSTA_KOD","Data":""},{"Key":"ULKE_KOD","Data":"TR"},{"Key":"EMAIL","Data":""},{"Key":"ILK_GECERLILIK_TARIHI","Data":"7/28/2009 12:00:00 AM"},{"Key":"SON_GECERLILIK_TARIHI","Data":""},{"Key":"ILCE_KOD","Data":"10"},{"Key":"YARATAN_KULLANICI_KODU","Data":""},{"Key":"YARATILDIGI_TARIH","Data":""},{"Key":"EXTRE_ADRES_KOD_F","Data":"E"},{"Key":"DAHILI_NO","Data":""},{"Key":"ISYERI_UNVANI","Data":""},{"Key":"ADRES_TEYIT","Data":"E"},{"Key":"ADRES_TEYIT_TARIHI","Data":"9/21/2013 12:00:00 AM"},{"Key":"TELEFON_TEYIT","Data":"E"},{"Key":"TELEFON_TEYIT_TARIHI","Data":"9/25/2013 12:00:00 AM"},{"Key":"FAX_TEYIT","Data":"H"},{"Key":"FAX_TEYIT_TARIHI","Data":""},{"Key":"EMAIL_TEYIT","Data":"E"},{"Key":"EMAIL_TEYIT_TARIHI","Data":"9/25/2013 12:00:00 AM"},{"Key":"CONTACT_MOBILE_NUMBER","Data":"1"},{"Key":"CONTACT_EMAIL","Data":"1"},{"Key":"DIGER1_TEL_ALAN_KOD","Data":""},{"Key":"DIGER1_TEL_NO","Data":""},{"Key":"DIGER2_TEL_ALAN_KOD","Data":""},{"Key":"DIGER2_TEL_NO","Data":""},{"Key":"TEL_ALAN_KOD","Data":"216"},{"Key":"TEL_NO","Data":""},{"Key":"GSM_ALAN_KOD","Data":"532"},{"Key":"GSM_NO","Data":""},{"Key":"FAX_ALAN_KOD","Data":""},{"Key":"FAX_NO","Data":""}]
```

I got an error;

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BankPozitif.CRM.Library.ZeusApi.LegacyDataResponse]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

How can I solve it?

Comment: How did you get from a JSON that returns a key-value mapping to a class with these properties? They don't exist in your JSON at all.

Comment: Why do you do Substring()? that removes the [] array nominators hence your error.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It is request class. Not response class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
{"Key":"ADRES","Data":"DENİZ SEMA Site: 3"}
```

change it to

```
{"Key":"ADRES","Data":"DENİZ SEMA", "Site": 3"}
```

Comment: It is Response string. It is not a problem. There should be 2 parameter; Key and Data, it is Data content.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I delete ".SubString()" and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You deserialize to wrong type.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(response));
```